# Ссылки из меню wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть ли возможность получить урлы произвольных ссылок из меню?

Comment: Что значит "получить"?

Comment: Допустим у нас есть некое меню, где допустим содержатся ссылки на соц.сети. У ссылок есть атрибут href который содержит в качестве значения строку. Как получить, вывести, вернуть и тд и тп эти строки в ссылках?